# Taking derivatives of complicated matrix expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I have to take derivative of the following expression (For example):

$$\frac{\partial \left( -x^T QBL y \right)}{\partial L}$$

where $x,y$ vectors and $Q,B,L$ are matrices with arbitrary (proper) dimensions. This is only one case I came accross, in general I want to become comfortable for this type of derivatives. Can somebody point a reference?

And also if one show how this derivative can be taken, I will be very happy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the matrices involved have entries coming from $\mathbb{C}$ or do you consider the expression that you are differentiating to be complicated? Usually the word complex is avoided when one is in the second situation (not only to avoid confusion, but it is also subjective).

Comment: The "matrix cookbook" (google it) is quite useful.

Comment: Michael, I replaced the complex with complicated. You are right that it is subjective, but I suppose, it is what I want to explain. I want to become comfortable with taking derivatives or doing other things in these type of complicated matrix equations.

Comment: leonboy, thanks for reference. But, cookbook only contains 'rules' not everything, and I want to gain insight to derive arbitrary matrix expressions. Cookbook only gives ready formulas, not the processes and proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful approach is to write the expression being differentiated as a trace and then use the cyclic invariance of the trace to bring it into the form $\operatorname{Tr}A^\top L$; then the derivative with respect to $L$ is $A$. In the present case, we have $x^T QBLy=\operatorname{Tr}x^\top QBLy=\operatorname{Tr}yx^\top QBL$, so the derivative with respect to $L$ is $B^\top Q^\top xy^\top$.

Comment: Thanks joriki! Trace 'trick' was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

[The Matrix Cookbook](http://matrixcookbook.com) by Petersen & Pederson is a good source.  I'm not sure the link is still active. However a google search can bring you copies easily.

Comment: Maybe you can find some of the information in this document useful?  http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-pederao/ADTalk.pdf.  Skip to the section on matrix differentiation.